# Cannot restore NuGet packages using Paket in Azure Pipelines (Artifacts feed)

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, azure-pipelines, paket

I'm trying to define a pipeline that builds for **.NET Core** solution. Dependencies are managed by **Paket**. A dependency is downloaded from **Azure Artifacts** feed.

In first stages I thought the problem was Paket and I was able to define a pipeline that builds without it (using a *private packages source*, our private feed).

Once I fixed Paket issues I got problems trying to get `dotnet restore` working.

This my actual YML definition:

```yaml
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.x'

  - powershell: |
      cd ..
      dotnet tool install -g paket

  - task: setCredentialManager@0

  - task: PaketRestore@0
    inputs:
      PaketPath: '.paket'

  - task: paketCredentialCleanup@0

  # I'm not sure the following task is necessary
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      filePath: './installcredprovider.ps1'

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'dotnet restore'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '*.csproj'
```

The `NuGetCommand@2` restore task fails with this log:

```
NuGet Version: 5.4.0.6315
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.5.0.12403' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\rjysskyy.m01.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\1cpdh2ma.wgd.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\5.4.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="d:\a\1\s\\" /p:RestoreConfigFile="d:\a\1\s\NuGet.config" /p:SolutionDir="d:\a\1\s\\" /p:SolutionName="ArtifactsVs"
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
   at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.<GetProjectReferencesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
d:\a\1\s\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets(219,5): error MSB3073: The command ""paket" restore --project "d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj" --output-path "obj" --target-framework "netcoreapp3.1"" exited with code 1. [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync>d__68.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
EXEC : Standard error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj]
d:\a\1\s\.paket\Paket.Restore.targets(219,5): error MSB3073: The command ""paket" restore --project "d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj" --output-path "obj" --target-framework "netcoreapp3.1"" exited with code 1. [d:\a\1\s\ArtifactsVs.csproj])
##[error]Packages failed to restore
Finishing: NuGetCommand
```

Anyway omitting it, `dotnet restore` fails the same.

Source of script `installcredprovider.ps1` is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/blob/master/helpers/installcredprovider.ps1).

Repository can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/anxkzgxf8pcqgyb/test-feed_copy.zip?dl=0) (feed URL is partly obfuscated).

Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help!

Comment: I was wondering if I need to use `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task with **restore** command (and proper settings). I'll try.

Comment: You probably need to install `.NET Core 2.0.0`  using `UseDotNet@2`n task. Please check below answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I created a test project for troubleshooting. And i found `.NET Core sdk 2.0.0` is needed for Paket.

If dotnet core 2.0.0 is not installed, Nuget restore task will fail with above error `"It was not possible to find any compatible framework version"`. And paket retore task will fail with error `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.0.0' was not found.`

After i installed `.NET Core sdk 2.0.0` with **UseDotNet** task. Both Nuget restore and paket restore ran successfully. Please check below yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '2.0.0'

  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '3.1.x'

  - powershell: |
      cd ..
      dotnet tool install -g paket

  - task: setCredentialManager@0

  - task: PaketRestore@0
    inputs:
      PaketPath: '.paket'

  - task: paketCredentialCleanup@0

  # - task: PowerShell@2
  #   inputs:
  #     filePath: './installcredprovider.ps1'

  # - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  #   inputs:
  #     versionSpec: 5.x

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'config'
      nugetConfigPath: './NuGet.config'
```

For above pipeline, Task `setCredentialManager@0` is also must, but the powershell task to run `./installcredprovider.ps1` is not needed.

And i also found above pipeline will fail to run on agent vs2017-win2016, for an older version msbuild in vs2017 is invoked while executing nuget restore command.

Paket restore, dotnet restore and nuget restore they all do the same thing(dotnet restore and nuget restore will call paket restore). You can only keep one of them in your pipeline. I tested and my project was successfully built with either one of them.

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thank you **so much** for helping! Using a second `UseDotNet` task is something I hadn't thought of. Unfortunately pipeline stil fails (https://imgur.com/a/WwSS6AJ). I'm running `windows-latest` agent, do you suggest another one?

Comment: Hi @gsscoder It seems nuget restore task cannot find `paket.exe` installed by the powershell task for some reason. Can you try including `paket.exe` in folder `.paket` and commit it to the source code.

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying late. I was very under pressure at work! I'll do the a test and let you know ASAP. Thank you

Comment: I've downloaded `paket.bootrapper.exe` and let it download `paket.exe`, than I've commited both. `NuGetCommand@2` fails. I've tried again removing the boostrapper, but result has not changed. Here the [log](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/2034f370e8f382b367dac1c62afbece2).